# clicking on a link with the same href value using selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html code that has two links but both the links have the same href value, but the onclick and the text are different.
I wasn't sure as to how to access the second link.
I tried using driver.find_element_by_link_text('text'), but I get a no such element found error.

```
<div id="member">
    <"a href="#" onclick="add_member("abc"); return false;">run abc<"/a> 
    <br>
    <"a href="#" onclick="add_member("def"); return false;">run def<"/a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to get the desired link.

One option would be to get use [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) and check `onclick` attribute value:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="member"]/a[contains(@onclick, "add_member(\"def\")")]')
link.click()
```

---

Another one would be to simply find both links and get the desired one by index:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_id('member')
links = div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
links[1].click()
```

Which option to choose depends on the whole HTML content. Hope at least one of two suggested solutions solves the issue.

Comment: says that it's not a valid xpath

Comment: if I use the second option, I get the "element not visible exception"

Comment: @esua can you share the link to the web-site so that I can reproduce the problem? Thanks.